# nvarchar(max) columns interfere with each other in SELECT statement, only through ODBC

Tags: select, odbc, max, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

In a recent update of run-time engine and SQL Server version (2008R2 to 2012) I have begun experiencing an issue where largish queries through ODBC come back with blank fields where there should not be any. The same query run directly in SQL Server worked fine.

I started to delete fields from the query and found that it was the five TEXT datatype fields in the query that were giving me trouble. The first TEXT field listed in the SELECT statement would show up fine, and subsequent TEXT fields would not show up. If I deleted all but two fields from the query, the remaining two would come through.

Since the problem is clearly occurring within the ODBC, my first thought was to switch my windows 8 odbc drivers from "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" to "SQL Server". This did not help.

Since TEXT is on the way out of support, I thought it might be the culprit. I converted all the TEXT fields to NVARCHAR(MAX) (I am also looking for unicode support). This did not fix anything. Next I tried converting the out-of-page datatypes to an in-page format NVARCHAR(4000). This fixed the problem, but it does not work across the board, because I have some fields that are longer than 4000 characters.

My questions:

1. What is the limitation of ODBC related to out-of-page data that is causing this issue. My understanding is that nvarchar(max) data is only stored out-of-page if it is sufficiently long (am I wrong about this). In the example table that I'm working with, none of the text data fields are longer than 255 characters, however the problem still occurs.
2. I could probably get by if I could figure out which fields need the extra length and only leave those fields in out-of-page representation. However, the size of the application makes figuring out the exact (and possible) use of every field time prohibitive. I hope I don't have to go this route.

Comment: The table in question has 33 columns, 5 were originally TEXT. The problem does not seem to depend on how much data is in the TEXT fields, because the same thing happens for blank fields.

Comment: I have just discovered fields with some 15000 characters, confirming that I cannot just use nvarchar(4000) for everything.